# zend validation not working in populate (edit form)

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
    UserController.php
    -------------

    editAction (method)
    ----------

    $UserInfo = array(
            'hdn_uid'=>$UserResult['user_id'],
            'username'=>$UserResult['user_name'],
            'firstname'=>$UserResult['first_name'],

        );

    $form->populate($UserInfo);
    $this->view->form = $form;


    Forms/userEdit.php
    ------------------

    $elementDecoration = array(
                'ViewHelper',
                'Description',
                'Errors',
                array(array('data'  => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),
                array('Label', array('tag' => 'td', 'placement' => 'prepend')),
                array(array('row'   => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr')),
            );

    $hdn_id = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('hdn_uid');
            $hdn_id->addFilter('Int')
                   ->removeDecorator('label')
                       ->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');        

            $this->setName('login');
            $this->setDecorators($formDecoration);

            $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username'); //Note this username and in conroller  $UserInfo arr 'username' matched so in the text fields existing username is populated from table.
            $username->setLabel('Username')
                    ->setDecorators($elementDecoration)
                    ->setRequired(true)
                    ->addFilter('StripTags')
                    ->addFilter('StringTrim');

$submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
$submit->setDecorators($buttonDecoration);
$this->addElements(array($hdn_id,$username,$submit));
```

**Problem**

```
   Server side validation not working, due to some mistake in the above snippet
```

**Detailed Info**

```
 Server side validation not working in the above code, when i clear the username and if i submited the button then program does not validated the field, instead it updated the empty value into table.
```

**Note**
This same code working for user add form. but it fails to work for edit form.

Comment: Could you post the full code ? Where do you execute the code that adds elements to the form within the form-class ?

Comment: Don't try and save space. Let's see the code. Especially the edit action. The flow of the data is important. According to your snippet you have no validation code at all. Only one validator is even present in your form 'setRequired()' and nothing at all in your controller action.

Comment: @RockyFord, sorry i already added this Errors instead of viewHelper in Decoration, still i didnt get validation, is there anything specific i missed on the above, advise plz

Comment: is that all the code for your edit action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is pretty much a standard workflow for processing a form in Zend Framework 1:

```
public function editAction(){
    //set up the form
    $form = new Application_Form_UserEdit();
    $form->setMethod('post');
    $form->setAction('/user/edit');
    //test for POST array
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        //validate form
        if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
            //get validated and filtered form values
            $data = $form->getValues();
            //do some stuff
        } // if form not valid it should redisplay with current data automatically
    } else {
        //if not POST display empty form
        $this->view->form = $form;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps some.

Answer (score 0):

This line fixed my problem

if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())